# sqlldr : Could I use the comma delimiter field terminate and optional enclose simultaneously?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a CSV file that contains a list of famous singers in the world. I want to import this file to Oracle DB using SQLLDR.

Contains of **singers.csv** is:

```
number,name,follower
1,Prince,100
2,Ludacris,100
3,Bruno Mars,100
4,Madonna,100
5,Miley,Cyrus,100
6,Britney,Spears,100
```

**control.ctl**

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0, errors=12000) 
LOAD DATA  
APPEND INTO TABLE singers_tb 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
optionally enclosed by '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(number ":number", name "TRIM (:name)",follower ":follower")
```

**singers_tb**

```
create singers_tb (
number varchar2(3),
name varchar2(255),
follower number
)
```

**error message**

```
Record 5: Rejected - Error on table singers_tb, column FOLLOWER.
ORA-01722: invalid number
Record 6: Rejected - Error on table singers_tb, column FOLLOWER.
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I know the cause of the error is the comma (,) on `Britney,Spears` and `Miley,Cyrus`.

How to solve these problems if I still want to use `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","` ?

Thanks you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Can you change the format of the data coming in, e.g. by enclosing fields in single quotes?  By the way, do you have anything against Taylor Swift?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : oh...No. This is only an example  :)...
BTW, I can't change the format.

Comment: The extra `,` in last two rows are pushing Cyrus ans Spears into `followers`column. Issue is there with the CSV itself. If you open the CSV in excel you can see that clearly.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you are in possession of `singers.csv` then why can't you change it?

Answer (score 0):

Your control file already has: `optionally enclosed by '"'`.
Make sure the data provider indeed provides that any field containing your delimiter arrive surrounded by double quotes.